# javascript code with adding up formula not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code written in html and javascript. what it does is generates positive and negative numbers using prompt, it then adds up all the numbers generated using the formula n*(n+1)/2. The code doesn't seem to work well because I'm getting a wrong value when it comes to finding the sum using the formula and user input. my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script language="javascript">

        var countpos = 1;
        var countneg = 0;       

        function pos(){
            var positive = prompt("enter limit for positive numbers");
            document.write(positive*(positive+1)/2 +"<br>");            

            while(countpos <= positive){
                document.write(" " + countpos);
                document.write("<br>");
                countpos++;
            }                                       
        }

        function neg(){
            var negative = prompt("enter limit for negative numbers");
            while(countneg >= negative){
                document.write(" " + countneg);
                document.write("<br>");
                countneg--;
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    What do you want to output? Positive or Negative numbers? <br>
    <input type="button" value="positive numbers" onClick="pos()"> <br>
    <input type="button" value="negative numbers" onClick="neg()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.write will overwrite the entire document when the buttons are clicked ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var positive = prompt("enter limit for positive numbers");
console.log(typeof positive);
```

that is a string, not a number, you need to convert it with parseInt or parseFloat

```
var positive = parseInt(prompt("enter limit for positive numbers"), 10);
```

or

```
var entry = prompt("enter limit for positive numbers");
var positive = parseInt(entry, 10);
if ( isNaN(positive) ) {
    //error message
}
```

Comment: still doesnt work. this is what i did:

var positive = prompt("enter limit for positive numbers");
parseInt(positive);
document.write(positive*(positive+1)/2 +"<br>");

Comment: He doesn't need to convert since he's doing some operations with `*`. Check this:
`var strA = '2';
var strB = '3';
strA * strB;    // 6`

Comment: @DaniloValente Order of operations dude. `"2" * ( "2" + 1) = "2" * "21" = 42`

Comment: @epascarello Oh right, sorry. Didn't notice the `(` `)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is treating them as strings. Changing your code to this will show you why...

```
    var positive = prompt("enter limit for positive numbers");
    alert(positive);
    alert(positive+1);
```

Try this..

```
 document.write(positive*(Number(positive)+1)/2 +"<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

As adeneo says document.write will override the text on document. 
Try this:

```
    var countpos = 1;
    var countneg = 0;       

    function pos(){
        var positive = prompt("enter limit for positive numbers");
        var str = '';
        str += (positive*(positive+1)/2 +"<br>");            

        while(countpos <= positive){
            str += (" " + countpos);
            str += ("<br>");
            countpos++;
        }                        

        document.write(str);
    }

    function neg(){
        var negative = prompt("enter limit for negative numbers");
        while(countneg >= negative){
            str += (" " + countneg);
            str += ("<br>");
            countneg--;
        }
        document.write(str);
    }
```

This will work one function at a time but i have given you idea now next step is yours that how you utilise it.